# TeamCity automatically update sources and merge to git repo

Tags: github, teamcity, pull-request, teamcity-9.0

Does anyone know if it is possible to update source files during a build (from an external source for e.g. like checking if there are new translations and merging those in) and then merge those changes to a git branch via a Pull request with TeamCity as part of the build steps?

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity has an 'Automatic Merge' feature. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Automatic+Merge) and the [related blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/10/automatic-merge/)